# Removing asInstance[T] from scala code

Tags: scala, casting, type-safety

I've written this scala code and I cannot work out how/if it is possible to remove the `asInstance` in the definition of class `Problem`.

The basic idea is that there are two hierarchies

```
Problem
SpecificProblem
ConcreteSpecificProblem
```

and

```
SolutionFinder
SpecificSolutionFinder
ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder
```

These hierarchies will branched in the future, but at the moment there is only one concrete class and its direct parents.

`SolutionFinder` classes operate on `Problem` classes, and on construction of a `Problem` we provide a `SolutionFinder` instance that we will operate on it. The type declaration of the `Problem` class/subclasses specifies which `SolutionFinder` subclass be used on it, and the `SolutionFinder` type declaration specifies which `Problem` classes it be applied to.

The aim is to be able to just call `solve` on any kind of `Problem` and have it use the appropriate methods.

As it stands, the code works fine for all the examples I have tried.

I *think* that it is correct to say in the type declaration of `Problem`, it is implicit (in the non-scala-keyword sense) that `S = S[S,T] = Problem[S,T]`. The compiler does not recognise this, perhaps because I'm wrong about this and perhaps because this level of recursive type definition is beyond it's capabilities. To get around this I have told it to convert `this` to an S using `asInstance`, which is a faux-pas which I would like to avoid.

So, is there a better way of doing it. Should I be prepared for unforeseen consequences?

```scala
object test {

  abstract class SolutionFinder[T <: Problem[S, T], S <: SolutionFinder[T, S]] {
    def findSolution(problem: T): Unit
  }

  abstract class SpecificSolutionFinder[T <: SpecificProblem[S, T], S <: SpecificSolutionFinder[T, S]]
    extends SolutionFinder[T, S] {
    def findSolution(specificProblem: T): Unit = findSpecificSolution(specificProblem)
    def findSpecificSolution(specifProblem:T): Unit
  }

  class ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder
    extends SpecificSolutionFinder[ConcreteSpecificProblem,ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder] {
    def findSpecificSolution(specificProblem: ConcreteSpecificProblem): Unit = {
      // Actual solution to problem goes here
    }
  }


  abstract class Problem[T <: SolutionFinder[S, T], S <: Problem[T, S]](solutionFinder: T) {
    def solve(): Unit = solutionFinder.findSolution(this.asInstanceOf[S]) // I WANT TO AVOID THIS
  }

  abstract class SpecificProblem[T <: SpecificSolutionFinder[S, T], S <: SpecificProblem[T, S]](specificSolutionFinder: T)
    extends Problem[T, S](specificSolutionFinder) {
    // Problem specific fields and methods
  }

  class ConcreteSpecificProblem(concreteSpecificSolutionFinder: ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder)
    extends SpecificProblem[ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder,ConcreteSpecificProblem](concreteSpecificSolutionFinder) {
    // Problem specific fields and methods with values
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val solutionFinder = new ConcreteSpecificSolutionFinder
    val problem = new ConcreteSpecificProblem(solutionFinder)

    // The aim of the codes structure is to avoid writing
    solutionFinder.findSolution(problem) // (which works, but is not appropriate for how this is used)
    // and write
    problem.solve()
    // instead
  }
}
```

Comment: best to avoid inheritance and instead use parametric polymorphism and/or type classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implicit inference that `S = S[S,T] = Problem[S,T]`. But you can add an explicit one:

```
abstract class Problem[T <: SolutionFinder[S, T], S <: Problem[T, S]](solutionFinder: T) {
  this: S =>
    def solve(): Unit = solutionFinder.findSolution(this)
}
```

A better design might be to disentangle the `Problem` and `Solution`. Perhaps the `solve` could be moved out of `Problem`, and require the `Solution` only at the point of use?

```
trait Problem
trait Solution[P <: Problem] {def solve(p: P): Unit }
class ConcreteProblem extends Problem
class ConcreteSolution extends Solution[ConcreteProblem]
def solve[P <: Problem](p: P, s: Solution[P]) = s.solve(p)
```

If you need a more sophisticated relation between `Problem` and `Solution`, you could create a typeclass for the "relationship", with `implicit` instances available:

```
trait KnowsHowToSolve[P <: Problem, S <: Solution] {
  def solve(p: P, s: S): Unit
}
implicit object ConcreteProblemKnowsHowToSolveConcreteSolution extends KnowsHowToSolve[ConcreteProblem, ConcreteSolution] {
  def solve(p: ConcreteProblem, s: ConcreteSolution) = s.findSpecificSolution(p)
}
def solve[P <: Problem, S <: Solution](p: P, s: S)(implicit ks: P KnowsHowToSolve S) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> The aim is to be able to just call solve on any kind of Problem and
>   have it use the appropriate methods.

Sounds to me like the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). I would not try to approach it in such an object-oriented way, though, if I was writing in Scala.

It's a little hard to give advice, though, because your use case isn't clear - what does the consuming/calling code look like and what's your motivation?

Comment: Yes, it involves the strategy pattern in part. The strategy pattern would be essentially providing various SolutionFinders, which is fine on its own. But there is also a multiplicity of problem types which need to be "matched" with the solutions at the type level (as in, specialist `Problem`s have specific fields and methods that need to be accessible by specific `SolutionFinder`s)